# Making a dropdown list in html/jquery, without following any tutorials

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

First of all, i know that there are tons of tutorials out there to show how to make a dropdown list, but i wanted to try myself with my limited knowledge to make a very simple one, and i am aware that i am probably doing it wrong, but still i wanna try it.

So this is my problem now, i have set up ul and li in html and i have setup a simple jquery code that it will slideDown the submenu when mouse enters and slideUp the submenu when mouse leaves, but it doesn't work correctly at all.

Code:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:400px;">
    <ul id="ul" class="menu" style="border:thin solid #090;">
        <li id="li">Test
        <ul id="ull">
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul> 
        </li>
        <li id="li">Test 2A
            <ul id="ull">
                <li>Test 3A</li>
                <li>Test 4A</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>




    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ul ul").css({"color":"red","font-size":"30px"}).hide();
    });

    $("#li").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#ull").slideDown(400).show();    
    });

    $("#li").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#ull").slideUp(400).hide(100);
    });

    </script>
```

All this, is inside one html, i am not using anything else, expet a CSS where the class "menu" is just this `display:inline-block;`

The problem is that dropdown menu doesn't work as it should. When i move my mouse over the Test the sub-menu appears, but this doesn't happen at Test 2A, plus when the dropdown list "drops", Test 2A follows below it aswell.

I can't explain the problem easily so i setup a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eAvQ8/)** which will help you understand.

Once again, i know that this is not right and i should have done it by using some other way, but i wanted to try using the few things i've learned so far to make a simple dropdown list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using `id="ul"` .. id should be unique in dom .. use class instead `class="blabla"` . I changed jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eAvQ8/2/

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution is to change id at one of the two minor ul and add a row in your function that call it. @Nick

Comment: Solved the first part of your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/eAvQ8/1/

Comment: You say "Test 2A follows below it aswell." do you mean the headers should stay at the same level vertically?

Comment: @harsha it is not good practice to add event handler to each `li#id` ids.

Comment: @rab : point noted.Thank you :)

Comment: So far the answer of user rab worked as it should. Rab if u can post it as a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Id must be unique.**

```
 <li id="li">Test

 <li id="li">Test 2A
```

Change to different id's or use a `class`

[**Corrected Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eAvQ8/3/)

And do not take `li` and `ul`  as Id's or classes.Those are reserved key words.Creates mess.

Comment: And just doing what you said will solve the issue? This looks like a comment more than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution is to change id at one of the two minor ul and add a row in your function that call it.

```
<div style="width:200px; height:400px;">
    <ul id="ul" class="menu" style="border:thin solid #090;">
        <li id="li">Test
        <ul id="ull">
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>
            <li>Test 4</li>
        </ul> 
        </li>
        <li id="li">Test 2A
            <ul id="lull">
                <li>Test 3A</li>
                <li>Test 4A</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>




    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ul ul").css({"color":"red","font-size":"30px"}).hide();
    });

    $("#li").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#ull").slideDown(400).show();    
$("#lull").slideDown(400).show();    
    });

    $("#li").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#ull").slideUp(400).hide(100);
 $("#lull").slideUp(400).hide(100);
    });

    </script>
```